# Установка css.background из объекта Image()

Tags: javascript, css

Есть такой код:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .btn {
            border: 1px red solid;
            width: 300px;
            height: 100px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="btn" id="btn1"></div>
    <div class="btn" id="btn2"></div>
    <div class="btn" id="btn3"></div>
    <script>
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {
            $(".btn").css("background", "url("+img.src+")");
            $("body").append("<div class='btn' id='btn4'></div>");
        }
        img.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c4/PM5544_with_non-PAL_signals.png";
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Ясно что `$(".btn")` найдет существующие три блока, и `btn4` не изменится.

Можно ли изменить именно сам стиль "btn", чтобы к последующим добавляемым объектам применялся background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо добавить `<style>` в `<head>` документа.

```
img.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c4/PM5544_with_non-PAL_signals.png";
var style = $('<style>.btn { background-image: url('+img.src+'); }</style>');
$('html > head').append(style);
```

Comment: А, ну да, как вариант. Почему-то сам не сообразил... Спасибо!